# Gluing the cover of an Apple wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Every one of the pins on the cover of my [Apple wireless keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Wireless_Keyboard) has cracked. The ones still there are holding on with an edge. Given the keyboard's age, I can't say these pins have a flimsy design. Lifting the keyboard to clean the sides of the buttons with a Q-tip is all it took for the cover to fall off.

[image: apple wireless keyboard cover]

I'm about to use super glue (it's not quite epoxy, but it's the closest to epoxy on the market) to glue the remaining pins in place. Before re-attaching, I'll wait 2-3 hours for the bond to cure to be sure I'm not gluing the cover back to the keyboard.

Have you tried this sort of thing? The easiest solution (just gluing the cover on the aluminum case) is not interesting, in case some maintenance is needed one day (plus, having replaceable batteries is kind-of a nice feature compared to sealed custom batteries). Can you suggest another solution, or confirm super glue works all right?

Please don't suggest to use scotch tape, unless you can suggest a brand that will detach cleanly, even two years from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no stress on this plastic cover during normal use. If the table is flat, the keyboard will sit on the two feet on either side of the electronics/battery compartment.

Gluing will work (has worked). It's not particularly easy to re-attach the tiny broken pieces, but that's a different story. Once the cover is re-attached and the keyboard is flat again, the absence of stress means this solution may last.

Ultimately, to keep the cover from breaking again, one has to remember not to pick up the keyboard by grabbing anywhere near the cover. Use perhaps either side, or use two hands from both sides. Likely, the plastic cover has broken off in the first place because it was picked up where it wasn't designed to be picked up.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to work, unfortunately.

I've attempted a very similar repair which only ended in failure (and despair).  The problem is the plastic and why the tabs broke in the first place - they've become brittle with age.

So with some patience you can get the tabs back on, but they will break off again, unfortunately.